# How can I generate random characters given a range of values?

Tags: java, random

For example I have a char variable `direction` that can have values such as "R", "U", "L", "D", how do I generate random values from these four?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of approaches you could take. I would create a `String` with the value of `RULD` and pick a character at random using [`ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt--). Something like,

```
Random rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
String directions = "RULD";
System.out.println(directions.charAt(rand.nextInt(directions.length())));
```